# DRF get_serializer_class doesn't pass

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here I have a viewset:

```
class TenderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ API ViewSet for Propopsition """

    queryset = models.Tender.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TenderGetSerializer
    
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        print('get_serializer_class passed')
        if self.action == 'map':
            self.serializer_class = serializers.TenderMapSerializer
            print('if passed')
        return super().get_serializer_class()

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def map(self, request):
        print('action map passed')
        print(self.serializer_class)
        tenders = self.serializer_class.setup_eager_loading(models.Tender.objects.all())
        serializer = serializers.TenderGetSerializer(tenders, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I'm getting data with `TenderGetSerializer` instead of `TenderMapSerializer` and `get_serializer_class` method doesn't pass.

Output is:

```
action map passed 
<class 'tender.serializers.TenderGetSerializer'> 
HTTP GET /api/tenders/map/ 200 [0.19, 127.0.0.1:55247]
```

Difference of serializers: `TenderGetSerializer` returns all fields (about 20) and `TenderMapSerializer` returns 5 fields.

Hope for you help.
Have a nice day!

**UPD:**
`serializer = self.serializer_class(tenders, many=True)` instead `serializer = serializers.TenderGetSerializer(tenders, many=True)` doesn't fix the problem

**UPD:**
The solution of this problem: get_serializer_class works **only** for actions with **POST**-methods. Thanks to [L. Letovanec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9574874/l-letovanec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to implement `get_serializer_class` method like this:

```
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'map':
            return serializers.TenderMapSerializer
        return super().get_serializer_class()
```

so return the serializer class instead of overwriting default serializer class.
Then use it in your `map` action:

```
    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def map(self, request):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        # rest of your code
```

EDIT (from comments): `get_serializer_class` method is called automatically on POST methods but not on GET

Comment: Yeah that works but I use the same method in other viewsets and it works :>
What's wrong with this viewset...

Comment: you are directly using `TenderGetSerializer` in your `map` method... `serializer = serializers.TenderGetSerializer(tenders, many=True)`

Comment: `serializer = self.serializer_class(tenders, many=True)`
output same, result too;
issue is method get_serializer_class doesn't pass

Comment: you have to call `get_serializer_class` method yourself, it's not called automatically for custom actions i believe

Comment: I did so for a time, but in other viewsets with other actions this method works without my calls, I believe this viewset is cursed

Comment: can you post a link to pastebin with viewsets where it works? because i really think you *HAVE* to call `get_serializer_class` yourself in custom action like your `map`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xF2e3bkx

Comment: Ok I've tested it on my viewsets and it looks like the `get_serializer_class` method is called on *POST* methods but not on *GET* :) in the code you posted on pastebin you used it only in *POST* so far that's why it worked

Comment: wow, thanks for your help, I mark your answer as useful

Answer (score 0):

return serializers.Default  instead of   super().get_serializer_class()

Comment: Method get_serializer_class is not callable in this case. How it could return anything?
Look at prints, they don't pass